# User removed and daily rep cap

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

For example, user A has three accepted answers and 20 upvotes. Now the user's reputation for that day is 245.

Now a user gets removed who once upvoted user A (from those 20 upvotes).

User A gets -10

Now since the user has reached the daily reputation points cap, it doesn't increment the counter of reputation points even if there is an upvote.

It should at least allow the user to gain +10 in this example.

---

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/260990/jigar-joshi?tab=reputation) the live example for UTC day 2014-07-08.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The *User was removed* event is purely informative, the rep change *doesn't actually apply* to the day it is recorded.

Instead, the removed votes affect the days *on which they were cast*. Those days are recalculated, re-applying the rep cap as needed.

In other words, you did not actually lose 20 points today. The votes were removed as if never cast, possibly affecting the rep cap(s) for those day(s). Because the votes affected were not cast today, this *does not affect your rep cap for today). You did *not* go down 2 votes today, and the rep cap still applies.

Note that the *User removed* line is deliberately vague, to protect the anonymity of votes. If you received +10 one day from a vote, another +10 on another day, and you were capped those days, it may be *you did not lose any points at all*, as the rep cap is reapplied and other previously +0 capped votes now count anyway.

Lets say the user did indeed vote two of your answer up, once on June 25th (when you were rep capped) and once on July 6th (when you were not). In that case, these upvotes are now null and void, as if never cast. June 25th is still rep capped, because you received more than 20 upvotes that day even minus the deleted vote. July 6th is recalculated and comes out 10 points less as the vote is deleted but there are no capped votes to replace the points. In that scenario your actual point loss is -10.

Comment: yes vote are removed so leaving user to 18 votes, so user A should have +20 if he gets +2 upvote, which isn't the case

Comment: @JigarJoshi: No, today you still hit the rep cap and received your maximum amount of votes. You do not get an extra 20 today because user votes were removed *some time in the past*.

Comment: @JigarJoshi: that would only apply if you received those upvotes that were undone *today*.

Comment: I have hit this today and found this post. Can you point to a Meta post where it's agreed "as designed" or any discussion about how this has been agreed, if any such post(s) exist.

Comment: @l3x: see [Identify question upon reputation loss from removed user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177684); note the [tag:status-declined] tag added by a Community Manager.